# Why __weak object will be added to autorelease pool?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, weak-references

```
id __weak obj1 = obj0;
```

equals

```
id __weak obj1 = obj0;
id __autoreleasing tmp = obj0;
```

In *Pro multithreading and memory management for iOS and OSX*.

But why the `obj1` need to add to the autorelease pool, I think making a weak pointer of an object should not affect its lifetime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{
    NSObject* sp = [NSObject new];
    NSObject* __weak wp = sp;
}
```

the above code is translate to:

```
id sp = objc_msgSend(NSObject, "new");
id wp;
objc_initWeak(&wp, sp);
objc_destroyWeak(&wp);
objc_storeStrong(&sp, 0);
```

1) `obj_initWeak` merely associate the weak pointer `wp` with the strong pointer `sp` to ensure that when the object pointed by `sp` is dealloced `wp` would auto reset to nil, which would not intecrement the retain count of the pointed object.
2)`obj_destroyWeak` destroy the association of the weak pointer and strong pointer.
3)`obj_storeStrong` in the last statement equal to `[sp release]`.

But as soon as we use the weak pointer, the compiler would generate a new reference for the object pointed.

```
{
    NSObject* sp = [NSObject new];
    NSObject* __weak wp = sp;
    NSLog(@"%@", wp);
}
```

becomes

```
id sp = objc_msgSend(NSObject, "new");
id wp;
objc_initWeak(&wp, sp);
id tmp = objc_loadWeakRetained(wp);
NSLog(@"%@", wp);
objc_release(tmp);
objc_destroyWeak(&wp);
objc_storeStrong(&sp, 0);
```

`objc_loadWeakRetained` would increment the reference count to ensure that `tmp` is alive in the `NSLog` statement.
`objc_release` reset the object to the original state.

In conclusion, this design of `__weak` ensure that during the usage of weak pointer, its state is consistent. The new implmenetation of `__weak` of `Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)` do not  postpond the release to `autoreleasepool`, but use `objc_release` directly.

Comment: This is quite useful. Could you provide the source of the Clang change, please?